# Installing Apache Web Server on 64 Bit Mac

Tags: apache, macos, 64-bit

I know that MAC OS X 10.5 comes with Apache installed but I would like to install the latest Apache without touching the OS Defaults incase it causes problems in the future with other udpates. So I have used the details located at: http://diymacserver.com/installing-apache/compiling-apache-on-leopard/ But I'm unsure how to make this the 64 Bit version of Apache as it seems to still install the 32 bit version.

Any help is appreciated

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your ~/.bash_profile which means that your architecture is 64-bit ant you’d like to compile Universal binaries.

```
export CFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
```

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://www.mail-archive.com/dev@httpd.apache.org/msg38674.html) claims that a flag for gcc (`maix64`) should do the trick. Give it a whirl, and if you need any more help, post back here.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that you may run into issues with your apache modules.  If they are compiled in 32-bit mode, then you will not be able to load them into a 64-bit apache.

I had this issue with mod_python, took a bit of thinking to figure out this was the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Don't export CFLAGS from your .bash_profile or any other dot file.  Your home directory could live on for decades, the system you're currently using is transient.

There's a guide on Apple's web site, [Porting UNIX/Linux Applications to Mac OS X](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Porting/Conceptual/PortingUnix/), that talks specifically about how to make `autoconf` and `make` and other similar build systems fit into the Mac OS X Universal Binary scheme.  If you're going to build cross-Unix applications on Mac OS X, you *need* to read and understand this guide.

That said, I strongly question why you want to build Apache 64-bit.  Just because Leopard can run 64-bit software doesn't mean you want all software on your system to be 64-bit.  (It's not Linux.)  In fact, virtually none of the software that ships with Leopard *runs* 64-bit by default, and most of the applications included with Leopard only ship 32-bit.

Unless you have a pressing need to run Apache 64-bit, I wouldn't bother trying to build it that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you would have read a bit further on the same site there is some information on compiling Apache in 64 bits mode!
http://diymacserver.com/2008/10/04/update-on-64-bits-compilation/